# How to animate a network growth from a contact list in Python/R?

Tags: python, r, animation, networking

**PROBLEM**: I would like to animate the growth of a temporal network using Python 3 and preferably libraries like networkx and matplotlib in the Jupyter notebook. However, I'd also appreciate any help provided in R language and resolving my problem.

**DATA**: I have a contact list in the following form:
contact_list=[(time1,node1,node2),(time2,node1,node3), (time3,node2,node1)...]
In the contact list I have 92 diferent nodes and around 4000 contacts.

Now I would like to visualize the growth of my network within time.

**ANIMATION**: My animation should have the following requirements:

1. at the beginning I want all the nodes to be present on the screen and have no edges between them.
2. for every CONTACT in a contact_list:

   ```
     *change a time count to the time assigned to the CONTACT

     *highlight with a different color nodes which are assigned to the 
     present CONTACT and draw a new edge if there wasn't any between 
     them before
   ```

Here are the example frames to the animation I would like to obtain:

[frames_to_the_animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JCkE.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: As a workaround, if you can save the images you can use [ImageJ](https://imagej.net/Welcome) to sow the animation together.

Comment: a few examples for R in section 7  at https://kateto.net/network-visualization